# Scale_y_continuous unexpectedly changes my data

Tags: r, logging, histogram

Trying to plot a histogram with a large data set (>50,000 data points). There is a very clear distribution, an initial peak into a second smaller peak, however when we log the graph, the first peak pales in significance to the second, when even logged, it should remain a higher value. Will be viewing my data zoomed in FYI, just zoomed out to demonstrate effect better.

```
ggplot(sman,aes(x=V1, fill = V3)) +
geom_histogram(color ="#000000", center=100,binwidth = 100)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = met.brewer("NewKingdom",4)) +
  xlab("Feature Length (bp)") + ylab("Frequency") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=14)) + theme(axis.title = element_text(size=20)) + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(face="italic")) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size =18, face="italic")) + labs(fill="Species")  + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=18), axis.title = element_text(size=22, face="bold"))  

ggplot(sman,aes(x=V1, fill = V3)) +
  geom_histogram(color ="#000000", center=100,binwidth = 100)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = met.brewer("NewKingdom",4)) + 
  xlab("Feature Length (bp)") + ylab("Frequency") + scale_y_continuous(trans="log10") +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=14)) + theme(axis.title = element_text(size=20)) + 
  theme(legend.text = element_text(face="italic")) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size =18, face="italic")) + labs(fill="Species")  + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size=18), axis.title = element_text(size=22, face="bold"))
```

Data is formatted as such, note there are no 0 values in the dataset (I have done V1+1 to transform them:

```
V1    V2    V3.   
1    S. mansoni    TE   
16   S. mansoni    noTE
```

etc..

[image: Two peak distribution (non logged)]

[image: Lost first peak (logged)]

Comment: I see two peaks in both plots.  Admittedly, the first peak in the second plot is very close to the second, but that's what you'd expect after logging.  Playing around with the bin width or using a log scale on the x axis may make things clearer.  Without data, there's not much else to say.

Comment: Thanks Limey, but surely the first peak should still be larger on the logged peak as it is in the first peak?

Comment: That would be true if the log transformation had no effect on the binning or the shape of the graph.  That's not an assumption I would make.  One way to investigate might be to produce frequency tables that simulated the histogram.  Or interrogate the `ggplot` object to extract the data underlying the histogram.

Comment: Just in case, you could double check the count of not log-able values e.g like`sum(!is.finite(log10(df$V1)))`.

Comment: Sum is 0, I do however also get a warning in my script about "Transformation introduced infinite values in continuous y-axis "

Comment: See 10.1.7 of [ggplot2: Elegant Graphics for Data Analysis](https://ggplot2-book.org/scale-position.html?q=scale_y_log#scale-transformation): it says that `scale_y_log10` function draws scaled data in the original space. This mechanism can change the peak.

Comment: It peaks should still maintain a vague relationship, i.e. the highest peak should still be the highest after transformation, however we do not see this here?